# In Altium, how do I create mounting holes for a through hole transistor?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, altium, cad

I am starting to learn Altium and I don't know how to create a through hole footprint. How do I get started on this?

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diotec-Semiconductor/BC337-40?qs=OlC7AqGiEDm8mBKTeby4Hw%3D%3D

Comment: Altium has several support groups and you should take that route preferably.

Comment: I haven't been using Altium recently very much, but I remember once you create a normal hole (not a through one) you can check its properties on the right panel and from layers choose multi-layer or something like this

Answer (score 1):

There exits very good tutorials on YouTube or Altium help pages.
Just to name on:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=63VKyVByZck

Answer (score 0):

Inside Altium Designer, creating footprints for your desired parts can be accomplished through various methods. Below, I'll Show two common methods:

1- Download from SnapEDA: A popular option is to obtain the footprint from the SnapEDA website. However, it's crucial to ensure that the footprint matches the specifications outlined in the datasheet of the component you're working with. Each component typically has its unique package, so accuracy is paramount and you should consider that.

[image: Snapeda WebSite]
<sub>Image source: [https://www.snapeda.com/parts/BC337-40/Diotec%20Semiconductor/view-part/?ref=search&t=%20BC337-40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbSRC.png)</sub>

2- Create in Altium Designer: Alternatively, you can design the footprint directly within Altium Designer. Utilizing the software's tools, such as those depicted in the accompanying images, allows you to tailor the footprint to match your specific part requirements.

[image: Footprint wizard option]
<sub>Image source: Photo taken from Altium software</sub>

Regarding the creation of pads, the process is straightforward. Simply navigate to the top menu in Altium Designer and select the 'PAD' option, as illustrated in the provided image.
[image]

<sub>Image source: Photo taken from Altium software</sub>

By employing these methods, you can effectively generate custom footprints tailored to your project's needs within Altium Designer.